# Vue.js 2.0: Component not rendering object change

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, onclick, click

I have an object that will be modified on a click event, however it seems a refresh or clicking on another element is required for the object to actually update. What do I need to do so that the object is updated without a manual refresh or clicking on something else?

My code:

```
<template>
    <div class="userTable">
        <input type="text" v-model="query" placeholder="Search for a user" @focus="dimUsers()" @blur="undimUsers()" @keyup="selectedUser()">
        <ul>
              <li v-for="user in userList.users" :key="user.localized_name">
                  <img v-bind:src="user.portrait" class="userPortrait" :class="{'selectedUser': selectedUserPortrait.includes(user.portrait), 'dimmed': searching}" @click="loadUser(user)">
              </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
....
props: {
    userList
}

data: function () {
    return {
        userSelected: {
            "name": '',
            "portrait": '',
        },
        searching: false,
        query: '',
        selectedUserPortrait = []
    }
}

methods: {
    loadUser: function (user) {
        this.userSelected = user
        return;
    }
    dimUsers: function () {
        this.searching = true
        return;
    }
    undimUsers: function () {
        this.searching = false,
        this.selectedUserPortrait = []
        this.query = ''
        return;
    },
   selectedUser: function () {
       this.selectedUserPortrait = [];
       for (let i=0; i<userList.users.length; i++) {
           if (this.userList.users[i].localized_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.query.toLowerCase())) {
              this.selectedUserPortrait.push(this.userList.users[i].portrait)
            } else {
              this.selectedUserPortrait.splice(i, 1);
            }
      } return;
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you `stopPropagation()` the click event inside the `loadUser()` function?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I called `loadUser(user, $event)` with `event.stopPropagation()` in the method and same thing. The object is only modified when the input field is clicked.

Comment: Oh, sorry, all you had to do is change `@click=` to `@click.stop=` - I guess I should have mentioned that. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Didn't realize that shortcut was available but same result unfortunately.

Comment: Clicking on the component in the Vue devtools also modifies the object, but clicking the image the event listener is attached to still does nothing.

Comment: `selectedUserPortrait` looks like it should be a computed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you expect to see happen, but this code works as I expect. Does it work as you expect?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userList: {
      users: [{
          portrait: 'https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=p1',
          localized_name: 'one'
        },
        {
          portrait: 'https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=p2',
          localized_name: 'two'
        },
        {
          portrait: 'https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=p3',
          localized_name: 'three'
        },
        {
          portrait: 'https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=p4',
          localized_name: 'four'
        },
        {
          portrait: 'https://via.placeholder.com/50?text=p5',
          localized_name: 'five'
        },
      ]
    },
    userSelected: {
      "name": '',
      "portrait": '',
    },
    searching: false,
    query: ''
  },
  computed: {
    selectedUserPortrait() {
      return this.query ?
        this.userList.users.filter((u) =>
          u.localized_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.query.toLowerCase())
        ).map((u) => u.portrait) : [];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadUser: function(user) {
      this.userSelected = user;
      return;
    },
    dimUsers: function() {
      this.searching = true
      return;
    },
    undimUsers: function() {
      this.searching = false;
      this.query = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.selectedUser {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="query" placeholder="Search for a user" @focus="dimUsers()" @blur="undimUsers()">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in userList.users" :key="user.localized_name">
      <img v-bind:src="user.portrait" class="userPortrait" :class="{'selectedUser': selectedUserPortrait.includes(user.portrait), 'dimmed': searching}" @click="loadUser(user)">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{userSelected.localized_name}}</div>
</div>
```